# Resharper go to file from class

Tags: visual-studio, ide, resharper

Is there a shortcut in Resharper, to find `.cs` file from class declaration and locate it in `Solution Explorer`?

Comment: The official R# forums are, so far, superior to SO for R# functionality questions. https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/resharper Also, if you turn on the *track active item in Solution Explorer* functionality, isn't this already achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  This corresponds to the menu option Resharper, Tools, Locate in Solution Explorer.

This is what I use in Resharper 7.